# while loop doesnt stop at a function c

Tags: c, data-structures, while-loop, fgets

I am having an issue with this function that I have created, it's been created to minimise the code in the main function. (I was taught you should have a minimal amount of code in the main function)....

heres the code (ill explain afterwards the issue in detail):

```
void startPrediction(struct TrieNode* root, struct TrieNode* pntr)
{
    char result[50];
    char search[256];
    char exitProg[5];

    while(1)
    {
        memset(&result[0], 0, sizeof(result));
        memset(&search[0], 0, sizeof(search));
        memset(&exitProg[0], 0, sizeof(exitProg));

        while(strlen(search) == 0)
        {
            printf("Enter: ");
            scanInput(search);

            search[strcspn(search, "\n")] = 0;

            if(strlen(search) == 0)
                printf("Invalid Entry, Please Retry!\n");
        }

        //check for a space in the word
        removeSpaces(search);

        removePunctuationAndSpecial(search);

        trieSearch(root, &pntr, search, result);

        printf("\n\n");

        wordSelectionDisplay(root, pntr, result);

        printf("Would you like to exit?? (Y/N)\n");
        printf("Enter: ");
        scanf("%s", exitProg);

        if( (exitProg[0] == 'Y') || (exitProg[0] == 'y') )
        {
            printf("Exiting...\n");
            return;
        }
        else
            printf("Continuing Program...\n");
    }
}
```

All this code is fine until the asking the user if they want to exit... If they put Y/y then thats fine and it exits, if they put N/n then the code will start from the top of the while loop and go through but not stop at the `scanInput(search);` function, which contains just a `fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);` line of code...

it would go past it then go into the if statement and print **"Invalid Entry Please retry"** and only after then will it operate correctly and wait for the user to enter something...

does anyone have an idea of how to get round this bug??

thanks

Comment: Don't use `scanf()`.

Comment: @iharob i didnt i used `fgets()` i just called the function that its in scanInput

Comment: Oh, `while (strlen(search) == 0)` is simple `while (*search == '\0')`, but without the overhead of an unnecessary function call. And again `if (*search == 0) ...`.

Comment: @iharob okay thanks, your answer works so ill mark it when i can :)

Comment: you may use `scanf("%s\n")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `scanf()` left the `'\n'` in the input buffer and when you call the function again it simple returns as if the user pressed `'\n'`, you might do this

```
int chr;
while (((chr = getchar()) != EOF) && (chr != '\n'));
```

at the end of the loop.